# Is good to use electron or angular 2 to build PC cross platform application?

Tags: angular, desktop-application, electron

I want to create an commercial application which can create socket and accept connection different device using local network,access native functions like file system,clipboard,start an app etc...

Is good to use electron or angular for this requirement? and then How was the documentation?

Comment: i think you can also use differents modules of nodejs that help you to make p2p connection or use the file system, also the command line. totally apart of which js framework or technollogy

Comment: So we can use different NodeJS module to get required features.Thanks for the comment.